# Boilerplate for phonegap with backbone js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, boilerplate, backbone-boilerplate

I want to use backbone for phonegap. I am new to these framework. I spent quite a lot of time in understanding the structure, still I am not having clear picture.My plan is to use boilerplate for backbone. But I m still confused how to proceed with this.

I would like to hear from anyone for step by step procedure of how to use boilerplate for backbone to develop phonegap application.
Which boilerplate from the git is recommended?
Can I get any link or video for the same?
Can anyone suggest whether I should use Twitter Bootstrap or Jquery Mobile for frontend.

Totally I have thought about the structure as boilerplate for backbone(require+underscore)+bootstarp (or jquery mobile). Can anyone guide me through the steps to follow.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I've used backbone for cordova applications. Just start and post a question when you get stuck. https://github.com/nitinsurana/Backbone-Cordova-Bootstrap-Boilerplate

Comment: Thanks a lot... I shall start with it.